# pop() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given for maximum stack problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

I am encountering the above mentioned error pop() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given for maximum stack problem when I was running the .pop() command, e.g. max_stack.pop(1000).

Am not really sure what went wrong with my syntax. Appreciate if someone can guide me on solving this.

```
class MaxStack():
    
    def __init__(self):
        #main stack for enqueue operation
        self.main_stack =[]
        # another stack for dequeue oepration
        self.max_stack = []
        
    # adding an item to the queue is O(1) operation
    def push(self, data):
        
        #push new item to the stack
        self.main_stack.append(data)
        
        # first item is the same in both stacks
        if (len(self.main_stack) == 1):
            self.max_stack.append(data)
            return
        
        #if the item is the biggest one in the main stack, we add it to the max stack
        #stack[-1] is the peak operation: returns the last item we have inserted (without removing any elements)
        if (data > self.max_stack[-1]):
            self.max_stack.append(data)
        
        # if not larger number in the comparison then we duplicate the largest element from the max stack
        else:
            self.max_stack.append(self.max_stack[-1])
                                  
    #getting items
    def pop(self):
        self.max_stack.pop()
        self.main_stack.pop()
        return

    # max item is the last item we have inserted into the maxStack O(1)
    def get_max_item(self):
        return self.max_stack.pop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_stack = MaxStack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop` does not take any additional arguments to self (which is the calling instance), so you may not provide any.

If you want `pop(1000)` to do something you'll have to implement it as `pop(self, your_param)`.